# MySQL add column with numeric category taking an increment based on another column value and position

Tags: mysql, row-number

I have a table in MySQL as described below

```
rownum,value,status
1,16,1
2,32,1
3,16,1
4,23,0
5,33,0
6,16,0
7,22,0
8,13,1
9,43,1
10,32,1
11,45,0
12,28,0
13,23,0
14,28,0
15,31,1
16,13,1
17,44,1
```

Here the third column shows the status of the row basis which I want to add a new column. The logic required is for every set of repeated values of 1 in column "status" the new column will get a number assigned to all of those rows. And this number will increment with +1 when the next set of 1s are found. the output table should look as below.

```
rownum,value,status,category
1,16,1,1
2,32,1,1
3,16,1,1
4,23,0,null
5,33,0,null
6,16,0,null
7,22,0,null
8,13,1,2
9,43,1,2
10,32,1,2
11,45,0,null
12,28,0,null
13,23,0,null
14,28,0,null
15,31,1,3
16,13,1,3
17,44,1,3
```

I am a bit confused on how this logic can be created and any inputs will be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Use user-defined variables. One variable holds the value of `status` from the previous row, another holds the current category. Whenever the status changes from `0` to `1` you increment the category variable.

Comment: Why do you want to get data in this form ? If it is just for display purposes, it is recommended to do it in application code.

Comment: @Barmar My intention wasn't to seek an answer but guidance on how this can be achieved as I wasn't able to find the direction to take. Before I had posted, I searched a lot but couldn't find this specific problem at hand, so I had framed the problem here. Please check out my other questions on the portal. Thank you for sharing you inputs...

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I am going to use the category column as input to another stored proc in my algo. Got your point about handling in front end app env. Thanks for providing the exact answer to my question...this has helped me a lot to understand how to use user defined vars...

Comment: @AnkurBansal I thought first comment gave you guidance. I'm not sure how to give more guidance than that without actually writing the code, as someone else did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in MySQL using [User-defined Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), and using conditional functions like [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). We store previous row's status value in `@stat` variable, and compare it with current row's status value, to get results as intended.

But if it is just for display purposes, you should seriously consider handing this in your application code.

Nevertheless, try the following query (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9fhx2FGL9AXpKN1L61njCN/0)**):

```
SELECT 
  IF( dt.status = 0, 
      NULL, 
      IF( @stat = 0, @cat := @cat + 1, @cat )
    ) AS category, 
  dt.rownum, 
  dt.value, 
  @stat := dt.status AS status 
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
   rownum, 
   value, 
   status 
 FROM your_table
 ORDER BY rownum ASC 
) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cat := 0, 
                   @stat := 0) AS init_user_vars
```